# Nodejs error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js

```
function findall(collecionName) {

  var model = mongoose.model(collecionName, schema);

  model.find({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {console.log(err);} else {return data;} }
    }


//express router
express.get('/get', (req, res) => {
      return findall(collectionName).then((data) => {
        res.send(data);
      })
```

The function findall works fine, but I get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined', when I navigate to localhost:4200/get.

I am new to node please can anyone show me how to get this to work

Comment: "*The function findall works fine*" it doesn't actually return anything - there are no `return` statements inside `findall` itself.

Comment: ya there is return data

Comment: Correct indentation will help us and you to find code blocks easily. Now is confusing at first sight.

Comment: `return data` is not *inside `findall`* it's inside the callback given to `model.find`. You are returning from the callback, not from `findall`

Comment: There are nearly 4600 results for a search for the phrase `[node.js] cannot read property of undefined` on this site. How many of them have you read to see if there is an existing post that will solve your problem?

Comment: I have read about 5 posts so far, and I have tried a few to no avail

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found that (...).then(...); is a Promise pattern. So the called function; in the above example findall should return a promise. So the code should look like the following:

```
function findall(collectionName){
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    var subModel = mongoose.model(subjectColl, schema);
    subModel.find({}, (err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            reject(err);
        }else{
            resolve(data);
        }
    })
})
 }
```

and the calling function should be:

```
 app.get('/get', (req, res, next)=>{
       findall(collectionName).then((data)=>{
              res.send(data);
          }) })
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `findall` currently does not return anything i.e. `undefined`, calling `.then` throws that error. `model.find` only returns a query object which needs to be `exec`uted to get a Promise object. This promise object needs to be returned by the `findall` function. Refer to the following doc on how to use the Promise returned from executing a query: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find